# Change text input background when it is fulfilled excluding placeholder

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to change the input background-color when the user puts in some text, but my input also has a placeholder and I don't want the color to be changed for the placeholder content only.

How do I achieve that using pure Javascript?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email adress">

if (formInput.length > 0) {
    formInput[0].style.backgroundColor = "#f9f9f9";
}
```

as You can imagine this changes the background color even with the placeholder in it on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the length of the inputs value. Also, reset the color when nothing is in the input.

(Color changed to red to be more obvious)

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = (this.value.length > 0) ? 'lightcoral' : '';
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email adress">
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
el =document.getElementById("email");
el.onkeyup = function(evt) {
    el.style.background="red";
    if(el.value.length==0)
      el.style.background="none";
};
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email adress" id="email">
```

Comment: does not change colour?

Comment: It does, the color the OP has given is light.

Comment: Yeah, but when I remove text from input background color stays. Is there a way to reset color when input is cleared ?

Comment: @user8993934 Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the value of input :

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("input", function() {

  if (input.value.length > 0)
    input.style.background = "#ff0000";
  else
    input.style.background = "none";
})
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email adress">
```

Comment: There's a problem with your code. After a single character is typed it doesn't change color and even after deleting it, it doesn't change back until typed again.

Comment: @Highdef corrected :) used the bad event ! bad copy/paste ;)

Comment: Yes that's it! :) Thank You! :)